# Getting "java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized body" when using ring-json on heroku

Tags: json, heroku, clojure, ring

I'm using ring-json to deliver json data to a front end that uses reagent to render some d3 charts. I've had the simple project working locally, but when I deployed it to heroku I got the following errors (from the heroku log):

```
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955857+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized body: [{:key "GB", :values [{:y 2.4555984, :x 2002} {:y 2.519768, :x 2004} {:y 2.4532163, :x 2006} {:y 2.420068, :x 2008} {:y 2.464492, :x 2010} {:y 2.321085, :x 2012}]} {:key "ES", :values [{:y 2.2434933, :x 2002} {:y 2.34095, :x 2004} {:y 2.1764393, :x 2006} {:y 2.0458074, :x 2008} {:y 2.1055703, :x 2010} {:y 2.041821, :x 2012}]} {:key "DE", :values [{:y 2.3088598, :x 2002} {:y 2.3240418, :x 2004} {:y 2.414952, :x 2006} {:y 2.2453654, :x 2008} {:y 2.2269878, :x 2010} {:y 2.1301556, :x 2012}]} {:key "FR", :values [{:y 2.292432, :x 2002} {:y 2.6937985, :x 2004} {:y 2.2779455, :x 2006} {:y 2.3077664, :x 2008} {:y 2.390625, :x 2010} {:y 2.3109756, :x 2012}]} {:key "HU", :values [{:y 2.5220544, :x 2002} {:y 2.570761, :x 2004} {:y 2.7397892, :x 2006} {:y 3.0420985, :x 2008} {:y 2.8456118, :x 2010} {:y 2.5978153, :x 2012}]} {:key "FI", :values [{:y 2.3738055, :x 2002} {:y 2.4264107, :x 2004} {:y 3.1687763, :x 2006} {:y 3.2200456, :x 2008} {:y 3.2385516, :x 2010} {:y 2.240783, :x 2012}]} {:key "PT", :values [{:y 2.8570483, :x 2002} {:y 2.8615985, :x 2004} {:y 2.649865, :x 2006} {:y 2.7748206, :x 2008} {:y 2.8316278, :x 2010} {:y 2.8707578, :x 2012}]} {:key "SE", :values [{:y 2.7565827, :x 2002} {:y 2.7382352, :x 2004} {:y 3.7057602, :x 2006} {:y 3.5786886, :x 2008} {:y 2.478958, :x 2010} {:y 2.2799134, :x 2012}]}]
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955860+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:115)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955859+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.util.servlet$set_body.invoke(servlet.clj:84)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955861+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__3274.invoke(jetty.clj:26)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955861+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invoke(servlet.clj:107)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955863+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955865+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955858+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.util.servlet$set_body.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:105)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955864+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955867+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955869+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955866+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955868+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955866+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
2016-08-01T15:50:38.955865+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
```

I'm not sure where to begin with this. Nor am I certain that it is a problem with ring-json. Do I perhaps need to set the headers somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Temporarily, here is a link to the project running on heroku: https://esd-viz.herokuapp.com/. The project itself can be found at http://github.com/ezmiller/esd-viz.

Comment: What happens when you start it locally with `java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/esd-viz.jar clojure.main -m esd-viz.server` (from Procfile)?

Comment: That is actually the command already in the Procfile.

Comment: Why did you as that question @MichielBorkent? What was your line of thinking?

Comment: "but when I deployed it to heroku I got the following errors" triggered the thought: this must be a production issue, so run it locally as in production and debug.

Comment: ahhh i see. forgive my ignorance here. the Procfile is for running in production? how would i run it? just run that command directly in the command line?

Comment: Probably just `lein uberjar` and then `java -jar <the-uber-jar-standalone.jar>` from the target directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118921/discussion-between-fraxture-and-michiel-borkent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lein uberjar
heroku local web
```

Runs the stack from the Procfile which will be the best way to test things locally. (hosts on port 5000 by default). This reproduces the problem for me.

As to the cause... the problem is here:

```
33 (def load-data
34   {:status 200
35    :body (essdata/get-json-data)})
```

The body you are returning is a vector, which is not valid unless you have middleware to handle it. So are the ring-defaults set up correctly?

If you compare:

```
env/dev/clj/esd_viz/middleware.clj
env/prod/clj/esd_viz/middleware.clj
```

You can see that in dev you have JSON middleware, but not in prod.

Hence when running with the prod profile, the vector is not converted to JSON like it is in dev.

Comment: I think that's it! Had no idea that there were separate files in that way. Trying to fix by adding ring-json into the prod middleware config.

Comment: ugh. now i'm getting an even more cryptic error: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ezmiller/public/images/localhost5000_2016-08-04_22-14-58.png

Comment: That's advanced compilation. set your production build to use :whitespace instead for now (you can change it later, but let's get things working first!)